# Name for a person hired to bring life to the party

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name, or job title, for a person hired to attend a party, such as a wedding reception, for the purpose of bringing more life to the party, by dancing, encouraging others to dance, by being friendly, and generally being a visible and positive influence on the party? This is a separate role from the DJ or band.

Comment: Are  you looking for *emcee* (master of ceremonies, the person who acts as all-purpose host for an event)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Party motivator**

> A party motivator is a person paid to entertain attendants at a party. Typically, party motivators are attractive young men and women who dress fashionably and attempt to engage guests in socializing and dancing.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_motivator

---

Notes:

I recently read an entertaining article about bar mitzvah party motivators: https://www.topic.com/the-bar-mitzvah-party-starters

But the phenomenon is getting fairly old at this point as attested in this article from 15 years ago: https://www.nytimes.com/2003/05/30/nyregion/job-description-life-party-proper-motivator-ensures-that-bar-mitzvah-celebration.html

That one's also about bar mitzvah party motivators.  Which is odd, but apparently party motivators are becoming common at b'nei mitvah.  My bar mitzvah probably could have used one.  My parents and their friends schmoozed quietly, while the young people climbed trees and had a pine cone fight - because that's what you do once you've become a man.